# How to get substring fom a string in iphone?

Tags: iphone, string

I've got some strings in the format:

```
="Netherlands Antillean Guilder (ANG)","Australian Dollar (AUD)"
```

I want to get the sub string between the parenthesis `"()"`

How do I do this?

Comment: In the future, please put more effort into the quality of your questions. Capitalization helps, quite a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sloppy way to do it:

```
    NSString *theString = @"Netherlands Antillean Guilder (ANG)";
    NSArray *someArray = [theString componentsSeparatedByString:@"("];
    theString = [someArray objectAtIndex:1];
    someArray = [theString componentsSeparatedByString:@")"];
    theString = [someArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

theString should be "ANG". Don't have SDK nearby, so there might be a mistake or two.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString *startfrom = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"("];
    NSString *Myword = nil;
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:"Netherlands Antillean Guilder (ANG)","Australian Dollar (AUD)"];
    [scanner scanUpToString:startfrom intoString:nil];
    [scanner scanUpToString:@")" intoString:&Myword];
    NSString *finalword = [Myword substringFromIndex:[startfrom length]];
    NSLog(@" %@",finalword);
    [startfrom release];
```